# Execute command from grep result

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, grep

I have a file abc.txt in my home folder.

`~$ cat abc.txt`
`ls`
`date`

I want want to execute a grep command like
`~$ grep 'dat' abc.txt`
which gives **date** in result and **date** is a shell command. So I want to execute the command which I got in grep result (**date**) in the same line of grep command.

Is it possible by using `|` operator like
`~$ grep 'dat' abc.txt | [Some command syntax like xargs]`   which gives the result current time like **Fri Nov  4 18:55:06 IST 2016**

Comment: Do you mean `cat abc.txt|grep dat`?

Comment: Yes I want the same. I think it gives the same as ~$ grep 'dat' abc.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?
<sup>note: this is using the bash shell</sup>

```
# cat abc.txt  
test line 1
date +%F  
test line 3

# $(grep dat abc.txt)  
2016-11-04
```

You'll need to be careful on what you filter from the `grep` command -- all of it will be fired into the shell -- as a single command! So, get a single line match with your filter.

PS: There has to be a better way for this but it escapes me now.
Would help to know what you are really trying to get done here.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I needed. Thanx! a lot for helping.

Comment: Also you can use `grep dat abc.txt|bash`